# Magento cms tag inside cms tag

Tags: magento

I have email template. To the email template i pass parameters. Inside the email template i am  using magento block. I want to pass the parameters of the email template to the block inside the email template

```
    {{block type="trips/email_details" first_names={{var first_names}} last_names={{var last_names}} ages={{var ages}} addresses={{var address}} template="trips/email-details.phtml"}}
```

I want it to look like this. However it does not support nested cms tags  , it just finds the first  closing tag "}}" and considers it as final.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to understand what use cases exist for having first names, last names, and so on as input parameters for a Magento Block. If the purpose is offering flexibility to your users..I think, in this way it isn't. I think it will be a better approach to remove the names and addresses stuff and process them within code. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes because of your comment now i came with the idea , to get this information directly in the block, by invoking $this->getRequest()->getParams();. However the general question still remains- How to pass a variable to this block? For example i may need to pass an order object to this block.